# Photoshop: Keyboard shortcuts for copying layers between documents

Tags: keyboard, adobe-photoshop

Is there any keyboard shortcut, or is it possible to set one, for the action of copying a layer from a document (and another one for the action of pasting it onto another document)?

I have checked Photoshop's keyboard shortcuts and the `Automate->Batch` options but couldn't see anything that would allow me to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Layer, CTRL+A (Select All), CTRL+C (Copy).  Go to the other image, CTRL+V (Paste).

(Command instead of CTRL on Macs)

Alternatively, use the Move tool with the CTRL (Command) key pressed down and drag the layer across.

I'm saying this from memory, as I do not have Photoshop to hand, so excuse me if I am forgetting something.

Comment: @AmV: You're welcome.  I recommend that you learn the keyboard shortcuts and how CTRL, ALT, SHIFT and SPACEBAR, as well as combinations of those, effect all the tools in Photoshop.  When you are more experienced, you will always have your left hand on the left end of the keyboard while using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both files open, you can drag and drop. Not a keyboard shortcut, but another option.